# NavigationBar resize on rotation leaves empty space

Tags: ios

- I have a `PortraitViewController`.
- I use *navigationBar* controlled by `NavigationController`.
- I have `shouldAutoRotate` return **NO** and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returning **Portrait**
- When I rotate to Landscape, I present `LandscapeViewController`.

My problem is when PortraitView is rotated, the navgationBar auto resizes and reduces its height. That leaves empty space below navBar.

Is there a way I can prevent/disable this behavior?

For the portrait view, I dont want that empty space to appear when rotation happens

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

After lots of try/error, I was able to keep NavBar fixed where it was in portrait view when device rotates by doing

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = Application.statusBarFrame.size.height;
CGFloat navBarHeightInPortrait = navigationBar.frame.size.height;

** Present LandscapeViewController modally via new NavigationController**

navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(navigationBar.frame.origin.x,
   navigationBar.frame.origin.y+statusBarHeight,
   navigationBar.frame.size.width,
   navBarHeightInPortrait);
```

Is that an acceptable way of doing what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed the issue by putting this in viewDidLoad:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom|UIRectEdgeLeft|UIRectEdgeRight];
}
```